# How do I mock a block argument in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Let's say I am calling a Ruby method with a block argument in ruby:

```
  Net::SFTP.start('testhost.com', 'test_user', keys: ['key']) do |sftp|
    sftp.upload!('/local', '/remote')
  end
```

How can I test that the `upload!` method was called with the correct arguments?

I could get this far, testing the arguments for `#start`,

```
  expect(Net::SFTP).
    to receive(:start) do |host, username, keyword_args, &block|
      expect(host).to eq("testhost.com")
      expect(username).to eq("test_user")
      expect(keyword_args).to eq(keys: ["test_key"])
    end
```

But I can't figure out how to test that `#upload!` was called in the block.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `and_yield` - this works best when combined with `allow().to receive` and `have_received` matcher:

```
sftp = spy
allow(Net::SFTP).to receive(:start).and_yield(sftp)

# execute your code here

expect(Net::SFTP).to have_received(:start).with("testhost.com", "test_user", keys: ["test_key"])
expect(sftp).to have_received(:upload!).with('./local', '/remote')
```